# Multer GridFS Storage File Upload With Association To Mongoose Schema

Tags: mongoose, multer, gridfs, gridfs-stream, multer-gridfs-storage

I can upload a file to my MongoDB using multer-gridfs-storage, but I am having trouble associating the file with my "customer" schema. Basically, each customer should have three types of files: Network, email, and password files.
Each file will be a .txt. My end goal is to have a show page for each customer and be able find the customer by :id and then populate the customer's three files.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const customerSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
          },
    address: {
        street: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        zip: String,
    },
    fileID:
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,

        }

}, { timestamps: true });


module.exports = mongoose.model("Customer", customerSchema);



// Create mongo connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGO_DB_URL);

// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('customers');
});

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: process.env.MONGO_DB_URL,
  file: (req, file) => {
        return {
        filename: file.originalname,
        bucketName: 'customers'
        };


  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });



post route to upload files

router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    res.json({ file: req.file });
  });
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow!  this is a good start at a question; please include details on what part of what you are attempting *is* working, what part *isn't* working, expected output vs. actual output and any error messages and such you are receiving; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have three fields in your Customer model for the three types of files. Save the files to different collections using gridfs-storage and then store the id of these uploaded files to the corresponding field in your model. This way you can keep different collections of different type of files.